# Compact objects in the category of $n$-categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, compactness, examples-counterexamples, higher-category-theory

An object in a category is called compact if the functor corepresented by it commutes with filtered colimits. Now what are the compact objects in the category of $n$-categories?

It was suggested in the comments, that it‘s the $n$-categories that are somehow finitely presented. I would be very happy about an exact formulation and then a proof, a reference or a counterexample to this claim.

Maybe it helps though, to consider the case $n = 1$ first. One can embed $1$-categories into simplicial sets (a similar thing is possible with $n$-categories which can be embedded into $\Theta_{n}$-sets). In simplicial sets, the compact objects are finite colimits of representables as per [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361282/are-compact-objects-in-presheaf-categories-finite-colimits-of-representables). But the inclusion does not commute with colimits, so I am not sure whether this will be useful in the end.

Comment: This is not really how compactness works. It typically detects the objects that are "finitely presented" in some sense, e.g. for $1$-categories you should recover categories which are finitely presented in the sense that they can be described as being generated by a finite set of morphisms subject to a finite set of relations. It's not clear what you mean here by the *category* of $n$-categories either, since typically you'd want $n$-categories to form an $(n+1)$-category.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I mean it as the category with objects being (small) $n$-categories and morphisms being $n$-functors. That is, all higher cells are ignored.